# Is there a better way to exit all recursive functions at once, rather than one by one?

Tags: c, recursion, boolean

Is there a better way to exit all of the recursive iterations immediately after the `if(a == b)` condition is met, instead of having to include lines 7 and 8 in their current form? Without lines 7 and 8 as they currently are, it seems to exit merely the last iteration.

```
bool recursive(int a, int b) {
    if(a == b)
        return true;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if(locked[b][i] == true)
            if(recursive(a, i) == true)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

It's not really critical, but I'd like to spare lines whenever possible. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. First you asked for a better way, then you said you want fewer lines. Shorter != better.

Comment: You don't need `== true`. Removing that will shorten it without affecting the clarity at all.

Comment: You could combine the if statements with an `&&` operator, as in `if (locked[b][i] && recursive(a, i))`.

Comment: longjmp may help

Comment: @Barmar can you elaborate more on why short isn't always better?

Comment: Take a gander at the CodeGolf solutions and that should be a good indicator on why shorter isn't always better.

Comment: Unless there are overriding concerns, clarity should be the primary goal.

Comment: @Barmar so current one is best?

Comment: I think the code you've written is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably write this like so:

```
bool recursive(int a, int b) {
    bool result = (a == b);

    for (int i = 0; i < count && !result; i++) {
        result = (locked[b][i] && recursive(a, i));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Introduction of a variable to hold the working result of the function allows for *testing* that result as part of the condition for performing a loop iteration.  That way you can terminate the loop as soon as the result flips from `false` to `true`, yet you don't need any code to distinguish after the fact between the two possible reasons for loop termination.

Comment: IMHO, this is a good example of my claim that shorter != better. But maybe it would make more sense if I knew what all the tests represent in the context.

Comment: @Barmar, I absolutely agree that shorter is not always better.  I am also inclined to think that more descriptive names would indeed make both versions easier to understand.  Even so, I actually find this version a bit easier to follow than the OP's.  Obviously that's subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could use a bit obscure functionality of C named `longjmp`.
It allows to jump back a stack over multiple function calls. A bit similar to `throw` in C++.

Firstly, return environment is created with `setjmp()`.
It returns `0` if to was a first call to `setjmp()`.
Otherwise it returns a value set by `longjmp()` called deeper in the recursive call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

void slowrec(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        puts("done");
    } else {
        puts("go down");
        slowrec(n - 1);
        puts("go up");
    }
}

jmp_buf env;

void fastrec(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        puts("done");
        longjmp(env, 1);
    } else {
        puts("go down");
        fastrec(n - 1);
        puts("go up");
    }
}

int main() {
    puts("-- slow recursion --");
    slowrec(5);

    puts("-- longjmp recursion --");
    if (setjmp(env) == 0) {
        fastrec(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
-- slow recursion --
go down
go down
go down
go down
go down
done
go up
go up
go up
go up
go up
-- longjmp recursion --
go down
go down
go down
go down
go down
done
```

For original problem the code may look like this:

```
jmp_buf env;

void recursive_internal(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) longjmp(env, 1); // true

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if(locked[b][i])
            recursive_internal(a, i);
}

bool recursive(int a, int b) {
    if (setjmp(env) == 0) {
        recursive_internal(a, b);
        // left without triggering long jump
        return false;
    }
    // returned with longjmp
    return true;
}
```

Note that there is no return value in `recursive_internal` because either `a==b` condition is met and `longjmp` was taken as it was the only way `true` could be returned. Otherwise, condition was never met and the algorithm exited via `return false`.

Comment: Since his recursive algorithm can return true or false, can you show how you would incorporate that into the setjmp/longjmp implementation?

Comment: I think you'll need two different value arguments to `longjmp()`, one that represents true, another for false. But you can't use true/false themselves, because false == 0 which is the initial return of `setjmp`.

Comment: @Barmar, true could encoded as 1 while false as 2